# Elasticsearch: long value max aggregation results in double value

Tags: elasticsearch, max, aggregation, long-integer

I store 64-Bit-Twitter-IDs in a long field in Elasticsearch documents:

```
"tweetId": {
  "type": "long"
}
```

I want to use [Max aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) to get the maximum id. Unfortunately I only get Double values (f.ex. `5.6253962514387763E17`) instead of my Long Id and I loose the last digits.

Is it possible to get the maximum of a Long field with full precision?

I am using Elasticsearch 1.4.2 with the Java client.

Comment: I don't know why it's like that and how you can fix it. But I have a suggestion: index the id as string `not_analyzed` and to get the max ID, use a `top_hits` aggregation sorting by tweet id descending and with `"size": 1`. If interested, I can provide a sample query.

Comment: Thx! But I cannot use `top_hits` as a sub aggregations of the `max` aggregation. And when I would sort by the string id, I would only get "String sort" not "Number sort" for the id field.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tweet IDs, but if all IDs have the same number of digits, you can do "string" sorting on them.

Comment: Unfortunately they may have different number of digits. I may add `0`s to short ids and use String sort, but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Added now a [feature request #9545](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/9545) for this in the Elasticsearch repository.

Comment: I believe this is an issue with javascript if you are using some UI to see this. Do a commandline curl and it should look good.

Comment: No, the values are stored correctly. I use the Java client, not a Javascript client. I think the problem is the [Max interface](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/max/Max.java) which only define the `getValue()` method with return type `double` instead of f.ex. `Number`.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to suggested in the comments, instead of using `max` you should use `top_hits` together with `sorting`.

The only difference is that you should keep the field `long` and not change it to `string` like suggested.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "last_crawl_id_item": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "sort": [
          {
            "id": "desc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```